# Sum of variances of transformed random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, linear-transformations

Having equation

$$\operatorname{var}(aX + b) = a^2 \operatorname{var}X$$

and

$$Z=2X-3Y+1$$

how can we calculate $\operatorname{var} Z$? Is it legit to do $2^2 \operatorname E X  + (-3)^2 \operatorname E Y $?

Or is there some theory that does not allow it? Thanks for help.

Comment: (1) where does your first equation come from? It is false in general. (2) crucially, if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent you cannot write $\operatorname{var}(X+Y)=\operatorname{var}(X)+\operatorname{var}(Y)$ (it is not true in general). You can if they are.

Comment: the first equation is formula taught at my university

Comment: edit:: it should have been lowercase b not capital B.

Comment: Are you **certain** they do not teach you $$\operatorname{var}(aX+b)=a^2\operatorname{var}(X)$$ instead? (where $a,b$ are constants). (The lowercase vs. uppercase $b$ is irrelevant. The key is that it's a variance, not an expectation, in the right-hand side)

Comment: oh... didnt notice typo, thanks

Comment: OK. In that case, point (2) remains valid. You only have $\operatorname{var}(X+Y)=\operatorname{var}(X)+\operatorname{var}(Y)$ if the two random variables $X,Y$ are uncorrelated (by definition, actually), which is implied by $X,Y$ independent. If you don't have any assumption on how $X,Y$ are related, then you cannot write that (you only have$ \operatorname{var}(X+Y)=\operatorname{var}(X)+\operatorname{var}(Y)+\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)$).

Comment: (I missed a factor $2$ in front of the covariance above. It basically behaves like the cross term in $(x+y)^2$, in short.)

Comment: Thus: $\mathsf {Var}(aX+bY+c) = a^2\mathsf{Var}(X)+2ab\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)+b^2\mathsf{Var}(Y)$ for constants $a,b,c$ and random variables $X,Y$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\v}{\operatorname{var}}\newcommand{\c}{\operatorname{cov}}$
\begin{align}
\v(2X - 3Y + 1) & = \v(2X-3Y) \\[10pt]
& = \v(2X) + \v(-3Y) + 2\c(2X,-3Y) \\[10pt]
& = 2^2\v(X) + (-3)^2 \v(Y) + 2\cdot2\cdot(-3)\c(X,Y).
\end{align}

This follows from bi-linearity of the covariance:
\begin{align}
& \v(U+V) \\[10pt]
= {} & \c(U+V,U+V) \\[10pt]
= {} & \c(U+V,U) + \c(U+V,V) \\
& \quad \text{since cov is linear in the second argument} \\[10pt]
= {} & \Big( \c(U,U) + \c(V,U) \Big) + \Big( \c(U,V) + \c(V,V)\Big) \\
& \quad \text{since cov is linear in the first argument} \\[10pt]
= {} & \v(U) + 2\c(U,V) + \v(V).
\end{align}